# C#, How to get powershell script file and pass some variable to script?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am new to using powershell in C# environment. I already created a multiline textbox to type powershell script to execute it and it worked fine. Now I want to get rid of typing in textbox and have 3 selected variables (Container, and NumIP) instead to pass to powerscript script file then execute it. How can I get these file and pass these variables to powershell script file in C#? Or do I have to create a script string in C#?

Here a working powershell script file, since it long codes, I am gonna put 1 line code where I want to pass these 2 variables to these 2 arguments.

```
    [string]$ContainerIn=$args[0]
[int]$ips2get=$args[1]
```

Here a C# codes,

```
protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clean the Result TextBox
        ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;
        ResultBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

        string str = "";

        //These 3 input varaibles will pass to powershell script to get specific results
        string env = "";
        string container = "";
        string numIPs = "";

        //assign dropdown selected value to variable to pass to script
        container = DropDownListContainer.SelectedValue;
        numIPs = DropDownListIP.SelectedValue;

        if (container == "H02" || container == "H07" || container == "H08")
        {
            env = "Prod";
        }
        else
        {
            env = "NonProd";
        }

        // Create a Powershell
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

        Command invokeScript = new Command("Invoke-Command");
        RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke();

        //Add powershell command/script functions into scriptblock
        ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
        invokeScript.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb);
        invokeScript.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

        pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript);
        Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();

        //splitting results in new lines
        foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
        {

            str = str + psObject + "\r\n";
            //str = psObject + "\r\n";
            //str += "\n" + psObject;
            //str = str + Environment.NewLine + psObject;

        }

        if (str == "")
        {
            str = "Error";

            ResultBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
        }

        //print out powershell output result
        ResultBox.Text = str;

    }
```

I know I would probably have to change this code, `ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke("{" + PowerShellCodeBox.Text + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made this work,

I just need to modify to `ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1 '"+container+"' "+numIPs+"}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;`

The powershell script argument will get container and numIPs variables.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to modify your scriptblock creation like so:

```
string sbstr = String.Format("{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1 -Env:"{0}" -Container:"{1}" -NumIPs:{2} -GiveInfo:$false}", envTB.Text, contTB.Text, numipTB.Text);
ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke(sbstr)[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
```

In order to get the local script file propagated to the remote computer to run, you will need to do this instead:

```
Command invokeScript = new Command("Invoke-Command");
invokeScript.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);
invokeScript.Parameters.Add("filepath", "D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1");
invokeScript.Parameters.Add("argumentlist", new[]{envTB.Text, contTB.Text, numipTB.Text, False});
```

Comment: What about the script file? Should I add something like `string script = @"D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1";` then add `invokeScript.Parameters.Add(script);`?

Comment: No, you can just pass the full path to the script in the scriptblock.

Comment: like what? Pass script to `Command invokeScript = new Command(script);`?

Comment: Look at the updated answer. I assume although you have not stated as such, that you still want to run the script on a remote computer which is why you are using Invoke-Command. BTW is the script on the remote computer or is it only on the local computer?

Comment: Yes I want to run a script on a remote computer(website). The script is stored in local computer where all these VS files are.

Comment: I mean the script is stored along with VS codes in different server. I am using different computer and use the asp.net website to remotely using powershell and use the script

Comment: I just edited it above and I was able to get the script file and run it default just fine. Now Where I can put `Get-FreeAddress -Env:"Prod" -Container:"H07" -NumIPs:2 -GiveInfo:$false` with 3 input variables(env, container, numIPs) in `ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;`?

Comment: See my updated answer.  Whether you use the FilePath or Scriptblock parameter, the line to add the ArgumentList parameter is the same.

Comment: There are error underlined for `-Env:"{0}" -Container:"{1}" -NumIPs:{2} -GiveInfo:$false`. Shouldn't it be `Get-FreeAddress -Env:"{0}" -Container:"{1}" -NumIPs:"{2}" -GiveInfo:$false`?

Comment: I modify above that the powershell script have 2 argument to get 2 variable. So how that work?